# Evaluate keras model with image data generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I have trained a Keras model using the `ImageDataGenerator` by calling the `fit_generator` method and passing it the `ImageDataGenerator` object.

Now I want to evaluate the model with the same `ImageDataGenerator` object. But I think I'm missing something.

I have my data in 2 variables,

```
ck_train = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(
    224, 224), classes=['happy', 'neutral', 'surprise'], batch_size=32)
ck_test = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_path, target_size=(
    224, 224), classes=['happy', 'neutral', 'surprise'], batch_size=16)
```

I have tried to evaluate the model via

```
deXpression.evaluate_generator(ck_test)
```

but I get this error

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0d318201cacd> in <module>
----> 1 deXpression.evaluate_generator(ck_test)

~/anaconda3/envs/gandola/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/anaconda3/envs/gandola/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in evaluate_generator(self, generator, steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, verbose)
   1470             workers=workers,
   1471             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
-> 1472             verbose=verbose)
   1473 
   1474     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

~/anaconda3/envs/gandola/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py in evaluate_generator(model, generator, steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, verbose)
    299             steps = len(generator)
    300         else:
--> 301             raise ValueError('`steps=None` is only valid for a generator'
    302                              ' based on the `keras.utils.Sequence` class.'
    303                              ' Please specify `steps` or use the'

ValueError: `steps=None` is only valid for a generator based on the `keras.utils.Sequence` class. Please specify `steps` or use the `keras.utils.Sequence` class.
```

Kindly tell me:

1) If I'm moving in the right direction? 
2) What am I missing if I'm? 
3) How can I do it by using the ImageDataGenerator object? 
4) What can be the proper approach to do the task I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The issue was of the `steps` parameter of `model.evaluate_generator`.

```
STEP_SIZE_TEST = ck_test.n // ck_test.batch_size
deXpression.evaluate_generator(generator=ck_test, steps=STEP_SIZE_TEST)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way can give you an idea:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    color_mode= "grayscale",
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=128,
    class_mode='categorical',)    

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    color_mode= "grayscale",
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=128,
    class_mode='categorical')

 #%%
hist = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
    nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)

scoreSeg = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator, 400)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the method 'evaluate' supports generators directly yet, so the original approach may work nowadays.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).